# SwiftUI - List that does not display

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I don't know how to explain it, I think a video will be more explicit ..
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UyuGaNA6NCo

I only want to display the information according to my choices, and I don't know where I was wrong, I am in the problem since some hours

My code :

**HOME VIEW**

```
struct HomeView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var travelLibrary: TravelLibrary
    @State private var isShowingSurveyCreation = false

    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: Alignment(horizontal: .trailing, vertical: .bottom)) {
            NavigationView {
                ScrollView {
                    VStack {
                        ForEach(travelLibrary.testTravels) { travel in
                            ZStack {
                                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15, style: .continuous)
                                    .fill(Color.white)
                                    .shadow(color: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.black/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, radius: 7)
                                TravelCellView(travel: travel)
                            }
                        }
                    }.padding(12)
                }.navigationTitle(Text("Mes Voyages"))
            }
            PlusButtonView(action: {
                isShowingSurveyCreation.toggle()
            }).sheet(isPresented: $isShowingSurveyCreation, content: {
                TravelCreationView(travelLibrary: travelLibrary)
            })
            .padding()
            
        }
    }
}

struct HomeView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    
    @StateObject static var travelLibrary = TravelLibrary()
    
    static var previews: some View {
        HomeView(travelLibrary: travelLibrary)
    }
}
```

**TRAVEL CREATION VIEW**

```
import SwiftUI

struct TravelCreationView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var travelLibrary: TravelLibrary
    @ObservedObject var travelConfig = NewTravelConfig()
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
  var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                Form {
                    Section {
                        Picker(selection: $travelConfig.index1, label: Text("Pays de destination : ")) {
                            ForEach(0 ..< travelConfig.nameCountry.count) {
                                Text(travelConfig.nameCountry[$0]).tag($0)
                                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                            }
                        }
                        Picker(selection: $travelConfig.index2, label: Text("Type de voyage : ")) {
                            ForEach(0 ..< travelConfig.typeOfTravel.count) {
                                Text(travelConfig.typeOfTravel[$0]).tag($0)
                                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    Section {
                        Stepper(value: $travelConfig.day, in: 1...365) {
                            Text("Durée du séjour : \(travelConfig.day) jours")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }.navigationTitle("Formulaire")
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {
                let newTravel = Travel(config: travelConfig)
                travelLibrary.testTravels.append(newTravel)
                presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }, label: {
                Text("Valider")
            }))
            
        }
    }
}

struct TravelCreationView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    
    @StateObject static var travelLibrary = TravelLibrary()
    
    static var previews: some View {
        TravelCreationView(travelLibrary: travelLibrary)
    }
}

//
//  TravelCreationView.swift
//  Final Travel Project Logistics
//
//  Created by Sefkan on 04/05/2021.
//

import SwiftUI

struct TravelCreationView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var travelLibrary: TravelLibrary
    @ObservedObject var travelConfig = NewTravelConfig()
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
  var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                Form {
                    Section {
                        Picker(selection: $travelConfig.index1, label: Text("Pays de destination : ")) {
                            ForEach(0 ..< travelConfig.nameCountry.count) {
                                Text(travelConfig.nameCountry[$0]).tag($0)
                                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                            }
                        }
                        Picker(selection: $travelConfig.index2, label: Text("Type de voyage : ")) {
                            ForEach(0 ..< travelConfig.typeOfTravel.count) {
                                Text(travelConfig.typeOfTravel[$0]).tag($0)
                                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    Section {
                        Stepper(value: $travelConfig.day, in: 1...365) {
                            Text("Durée du séjour : \(travelConfig.day) jours")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }.navigationTitle("Formulaire")
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {
                let newTravel = Travel(config: travelConfig)
                travelLibrary.testTravels.append(newTravel)
                presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }, label: {
                Text("Valider")
            }))
            
        }
    }
}

struct TravelCreationView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    
    @StateObject static var travelLibrary = TravelLibrary()
    
    static var previews: some View {
        TravelCreationView(travelLibrary: travelLibrary)
    }
}//
//  TravelCreationView.swift
//  Final Travel Project Logistics
//
//  Created by Sefkan on 04/05/2021.
//

import SwiftUI

struct TravelCreationView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var travelLibrary: TravelLibrary
    @ObservedObject var travelConfig = NewTravelConfig()
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
  var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                Form {
                    Section {
                        Picker(selection: $travelConfig.index1, label: Text("Pays de destination : ")) {
                            ForEach(0 ..< travelConfig.nameCountry.count) {
                                Text(travelConfig.nameCountry[$0]).tag($0)
                                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                            }
                        }
                        Picker(selection: $travelConfig.index2, label: Text("Type de voyage : ")) {
                            ForEach(0 ..< travelConfig.typeOfTravel.count) {
                                Text(travelConfig.typeOfTravel[$0]).tag($0)
                                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    Section {
                        Stepper(value: $travelConfig.day, in: 1...365) {
                            Text("Durée du séjour : \(travelConfig.day) jours")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }.navigationTitle("Formulaire")
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {
                let newTravel = Travel(config: travelConfig)
                travelLibrary.testTravels.append(newTravel)
                presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }, label: {
                Text("Valider")
            }))
            
        }
    }
}

struct TravelCreationView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    
    @StateObject static var travelLibrary = TravelLibrary()
    
    static var previews: some View {
        TravelCreationView(travelLibrary: travelLibrary)
    }
}
```

**TRAVELCELLVIEW**

```
//
//  TravelCellView.swift
//  Final Travel Project Logistics
//
//  Created by Sefkan on 04/05/2021.
//

import SwiftUI

struct TravelCellView: View {
    
    let travel : Travel
    
    var body: some View {
        
        HStack {
            Image(travel.flagCountry)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.fill/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                .frame(width: 80, height: 80)
                .clipShape(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/Circle()/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 4))
                .shadow(radius: 10)
                .padding(.trailing, 8)
            VStack(alignment : .leading) {
                Text(travel.nameCountry)
                    .font(.title3)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                    .padding(.bottom, -4)
                Text("Durée du voyage: \(travel.day) jours")
                    .font(.subheadline)
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                    .padding(.bottom, -4)
                Text(travel.typeOfTravel)
                    .font(.subheadline)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                
            }
            Spacer()
            FavouriteButtonView()
        }.padding()
    }
}

struct TravelCellView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    
        private static let testTravel = Travel(flagCountry: "USAflag", nameCountry: "États-Unis", typeOfTravel: "Tourisme", day: 0, isFavourite: false)
    
    static var previews: some View {
        TravelCellView(travel: testTravel)
            .previewLayout(.sizeThatFits)
    }
}
```

**DATA VIEW**

```
import Foundation

struct Travel: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID().uuidString
    let flagCountry: String
    let nameCountry: String
    let typeOfTravel: String
    let day: Int
    var isFavourite: Bool
    
    init(flagCountry: String, nameCountry: String, typeOfTravel: String, day: Int, isFavourite: Bool) {
        self.flagCountry = flagCountry
        self.nameCountry = nameCountry
        self.typeOfTravel = typeOfTravel
        self.day = day
        self.isFavourite = isFavourite
    }
    
    init(config: NewTravelConfig) {
        flagCountry = ""
        nameCountry = ""
        typeOfTravel = ""
        day = 0
        isFavourite = false
    }
}

class TravelLibrary: ObservableObject {
   
    @Published var testTravels = [
    
    Travel(flagCountry: "USAflag", nameCountry: "États-Unis", typeOfTravel: "Tourisme", day: 0, isFavourite: false),
    Travel(flagCountry: "Japanflag", nameCountry: "Japon", typeOfTravel: "Tourisme", day: 0, isFavourite: true),
    Travel(flagCountry: "Germanflag", nameCountry: "Allemagne", typeOfTravel: "Tourisme", day: 0, isFavourite: false)

]
}


class NewTravelConfig: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var nameCountry = ["États-Unis", "Japon", "Allemagne"]
    @Published var typeOfTravel = ["Tourisme", "Business"]
    @Published var day = 0
    @Published var index1 = 0
    @Published var index2 = 0
    
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is inside the `Travel` struct. You have two init() methods, and the issue is in the one where you pass your config.

You are passing the config to it, but not using any of these values from the config.

Here is the correct one:

```
init(config: NewTravelConfig) {
    flagCountry = ""
    nameCountry = config.nameCountry[config.index1]
    typeOfTravel = config.typeOfTravel[config.index2]
    day = config.day
    isFavourite = false
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I had these settings but didn't think about setting it like this, again thanks!

Comment: However, all the information appears except the image, do you know how? Thanks

Comment: You will have to set the flagCountry String accordingly